# Сортировка по алфавиту и числам в MYSQL в строках с числами и буквами

Tags: sql, mysql

Привет.Есть строки в которых могут быть как и буквы так и числа.
Как отсортировать их только по числовому значению или по буквенному без чисел?
Читал что есть функции DEPTNO и ENAME,но они не работают в MYSQL.Как можно создать их реализацию в MYSQL?

Comment: Поясните. Строки "a1b2c3" и "d4e5f6" должны сортироваться: a) при буквенном сравнении как "abc" и "def", 2) при цифровом - как числа 123 и 456? Или чтобы при буквенном сравнепнии учитывалась только часть до цифр, а при цифровом выделялась часть до букв?

Comment: вариант А нужен

Comment: Отсортировать после выборки. Потому как подобная замена в MySQL выглядит примерно так (и это только удаление 1,2,3):

    SELECT s3 FROM
    (SELECT REPLACE(s2, '3', '') as s3 FROM
    (SELECT REPLACE(s1, '2', '') as s2 FROM
    (SELECT REPLACE(`string`, '1', '') as s1 FROM `table`) as s1) as s2) as s3

Comment: @klopp, зачем так длинно. Всего 10 реплейсов:
SELECT *, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`string`, '1', ''),'2',''),'3','')
...<и т.д.> as c1 FROM `table` 
order by c1

Comment: Да какая разница, всё равно извращение это. Как и сама постановка задачи :)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте преобразовать типы данных. Конечно надо учитывать, какие значения у вас в сортируемом поле, но иногда достаточно сделать следующее:

```
SELECT `field_name` FROM `table_name` ORDER BY CAST( `field_name` AS SIGNED )
// или же просто
SELECT `field_name` FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `field_name` + 0
```