# MySQL: как сортировать по текстовому полю varchar() по числу в начале поля

Tags: mysql

В таблице MySQL есть колонка, тип которой `varchar(255)`. В ней хранятся краткие тексты и в начале каждого стоит число. Например есть запись которая начинается с 30, есть с 50, а есть та которая начинается со 100. Когда пытаюсь вывести записи на сайте и посортировать их по данному полю, то запись, которая начинается со 100, ставит первой, потом 30, потом 50 и т.д.

Насколько понимаю 100 воспринимается как 10.

Как решить проблему, не меняя структуру таблицы?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/199544/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B2-mysql-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Answer (score 1):

Если вызвать операцию преобразования типов `CAST` то MySQL первые цифры превратит в число, а остальные отбросит

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY CAST(str_field AS SIGNED)
```